# Document position of an element in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I have some javascript code that uses obj.offsetLeft and obj.offsetTop to get an image position, then hovers an element at that location.
However, long story short, Ive had to embed this html inside an iframe which sits inside a main page.
In IE7, the hover element appears in its correct location fine, until the user scrolls the page. As the page is scrolled downwards, the hovered element seems to move downwards also, losing sync with the real position.

I tried using a do while loop to cycle through offsetParent, adding up the offsets. But this seems to only get as high as the iframe.

Is there any other way to accurately retrieve the position of an element inside an iframe, relative to the entire page?

Answer (score 0):

And you can't use some CSS positions to achieve that?
Otherwise, you have to calculate the iframe position and add it to the positions calculated inside the iframe to get the position "document wise"

Comment: No. I have a feeling its scrollTop property of the body I need. But as its javascript executing inside the iframe, I dont know if I can retrieve the scrollTop value of the root body (outside the iframe)